# Compile-time only Nuget dependency (FxCop)

Tags: .net-core, nuget, .net-standard, fxcop, roslyn-code-analysis

I am creating a .Net Standard 2.0 Nuget package and I want to perform static code analysis for the build. However, when I add the [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers) package it becomes a runtime dependency, so any projects that reference my Nuget package are also installing analyzers. I feel those should be opt-in concerns by the calling code.

Is there anyway to prevent that dependency from being enforced?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ended up finding the solution on my own. It just took a little more research on the [Package Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files) syntax in project files, specifically [Controlling Dependency Assets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#controlling-dependency-assets). The key was to open up the *.csproj file and add a PrivateAssets node like the following (note ExcludeAssets and IncludeAssets are set to the default values and could have been omitted):

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers" Version="2.6.1">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <ExcludeAssets>none</ExcludeAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>all</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
```

Comment: Any ideas on how to have the same behavior while using packages.config?